# Showing a Random Variable is Discrete from the Characteristic Function

Tags: probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Question:

> The characteristic func. of a r.v. X is $$\dfrac{e^{it}(1-e^{nit})}{n(i-e^{it})}$$
>   Show that X is a discrete r.v with $p(x)=\dfrac1n$ for $x=1,2,\cdots n.$

Can one please help me to show the if X random variable is discrete using the characteristic function?
I couldn't solve and actually I didn't understand how to solve.

Comment: In your future posts, i request you not to add an external link to the question, but to take the time to type it out..

Comment: For the future, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax guide.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, note $\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k$, so the characteristic function is $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^ne^{jit}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood that it looks like discrete uniform distribution. But still I couldn' understand your answer.

Comment: I think the suggestion is that if you replace $e^{it}$ in the characteristic function with $z$, removing $t$, and have a meaningful real Taylor series then you have found a probability generating function for a discrete distribution.  So  $e^{\lambda(e^{it}-1)} \to e^{\lambda(z-1)}$ and that works (a Poisson distribution), but $\frac{e^{it}-1}{it} \to \frac{z-1}{\log_e(z)}$ does not work as it does not have a Taylor series (uniform distribution form $0$ to $1$)

Answer (score 0):

The general question, of determining if a random variable $X$ is discrete by examining its characteristic function $\varphi_X$, is hard.
Lukacs's *Characteristic Functions* discusses this on pp. 18-20.
If there exists a $t\ne0$ such that $|\varphi_X(t)|=1$, then $X$ is a lattice random variable and hence discrete.  Define $L$ by $$L=\limsup_{|t|\to\infty}|\varphi_X(t)|.$$
If $X$ is discrete, then $L=1$, so
if $L<1$ then $X$ is not discrete.  But if $L=1$ the most one can conclude in general is that the Lebesgue decomposition of the distribution of $X$ into absolutely continuous, singular continuous, and discrete components contains no absolutely continuous component.
But  the distribution of $X$ might be discrete or might be singular, or might be a mixture of the two.